# Error en Function PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

estoy aprendiendo a desarrollar en el entorno de PostgreSQL , y estoy tratando de crear una store procedure pero me sale el siguiente error , ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este error?
no me esta reconociendo los campos de mi tabla que ya existe

```
create function LoginUsuario(usu text,pas text) returns integer
as 
$$
declare status integer := 0;
select u.CorUsu,u.PasUsu,
case 
when usu:=CorUsu and pas:=PasUsu then status=1
else status=0
from Usuario u

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

este es el error que me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por qué cuando haces `when usu:=CorUsu and pas:=PasUsu then status=1` no pones `when usu:=u.CorUsu and pas:=u.PasUsu then status=1` como con la línea del `SELECT`?. Por otro lado, mira a ver si ese esquema lo tienes y es el que estás usando. `select current_schemas(true);` y `select current_schema;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te faltan varias cosas como por ejemplo:

- clausulas `BEGIN..END` en la función plpgsql
- error de sintaxis en la clausula CASE (sobre `:=`, falta el `end`)
- y el `;` al final de sentencia SQL

Quedaría así:

```
create function LoginUsuario(usu text,pas text) returns integer
as 
$$
declare status integer := 0;
begin
select u.CorUsu,u.PasUsu,
case 
when usu=CorUsu and pas=PasUsu then status=1
else status=0
end
from Usuario u;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```